# Illegal transformation of condition for asymptotes?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

Obviously, the condition for two functions to be asymptotic is $\lim \bigl(f(x) - g(x)\bigr) = 0$.
But shouldn't that be equivalent to:
\begin{align}
&&\lim f(x) - \lim g(x) &= 0 \\
\implies&& \lim f(x) &= \lim g(x) \\
\implies&& \lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} &= 1. 
\end{align}
I can't see where I violated the rules for calculations of limits.
Thanks!

Comment: Try to construct an example where the limit of the difference of two functions exists, but the limits themselves may not.

Comment: @Noah Solomon: I'm not sure whether I understood your comment but if you're looking for an example where only the second equation is fulfilled : f(x)= x^2; g(x)= x^2+1

Comment: Notation: wrap your mathematical expressions in dollar signs for better formatting, e.g. `$g(x) = x^2 + 1$` produces $g(x) = x^2 + 1$, and read through [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more help formatting math.

Comment: The condition for $f$ to be asymptotic to $g$ as $x\to x_0$ is $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$. It is *not* $\lim_{x\to x_0}(f-g)=0$

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your limits are for $x \to \infty$, but the essential arguments still hold with a bit of tweaking if you intend $x \to a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

**If $g(x)$ is bounded away from $0$ in magnitude in a neighborhood of $\infty$,** i.e. there exists some $x_0$ and some $m > 0$ such that $\lvert g(x) \rvert \geq m$ for all $x \geq x_0$, then your conclusion follows, *but not by the calculation that you've shown which relies on each individual limit existing (not necessary).*

Here's a proof:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \Biggl\lvert \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \Biggr\rvert 
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} 
   \frac{\bigl\lvert f(x) - g(x) + g(x) \bigr\rvert}{\lvert g(x) \rvert} \\
&\leq \lim_{x \to \infty} 
   \frac{\bigl\lvert f(x) - g(x) \bigr\rvert + \bigl\lvert g(x) \bigr\rvert} 
   {\lvert g(x) \rvert} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \biggl( \frac{\bigl\lvert f(x) - g(x) \bigr\rvert} 
   {\lvert g(x) \rvert} 
   + \frac{\lvert g(x) \rvert}{\lvert g(x) \rvert} \biggr) \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\bigl\lvert f(x) - g(x) \bigr\rvert} 
   {\lvert g(x) \rvert} 
   + \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\lvert g(x) \rvert}{\lvert g(x) \rvert} \\
&\leq \frac{1}{m} \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} \bigl\lvert f(x) - g(x) \bigr\rvert 
   + \lim_{x \to \infty} 1 \\ 
&= \frac{1}{m} \cdot 0 + 1 \\[2pt]
&= 1
\end{align}
I leave it to you to convince yourself that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1
$$
as a consequence. If you like, just limit yourself to non-negative valued functions, so you can ignore the absolute values entirely.

Without the given hypothesis, though, it's easy to come up with counterexamples, e.g.
functions $f$ and $g$ for which $\lim_{x \to \infty} \bigl( f(x) - g(x) \bigr) = 0$ and yet the limit of the quotient is different.

In fact, we can make the limit any value $L > 0$ that we want. Take, for example,
$$
f(x) = \frac{L}{x} \quad\text{and}\quad g(x) = \frac{1}{x}.
$$
Then, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \bigl( f(x) - g(x) \bigr) = 0$ yet
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L \neq 0.
$$
Or with
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \quad\text{and}\quad g(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}, 
$$
we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} \bigl( f(x) - g(x) \bigr) = 0$ yet
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \infty.
$$
In all of these examples, the crucial hypothesis for the theorem above fails as $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$, hence can't be bounded away from $0$.